# Select multi identity values for multiple inserts along with columns not inserted into the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am inserting only 1 column into TempId table i.e name from a select statement
How do i get corresponding orderId for the identity column.

```
INSERT INTO tempId 
output inserted.ID 
Select name FROM (
select 'erty' as name, 1 as orderid union 
select 'rth' as name, 2 as orderid union 
select 'yt' as name, 3 as orderid union 
select '345' as name, 4 as orderid union 
select 'rtyu' as name, 5 as orderid union 
select 'uio' as name, 6 as orderid union 
select 'yu' as name, 7 as orderid union 
select 'xzf' as name, 8 as orderid
) as a
```

PS Note: SELECT with union is only done for sample query. Ideally I will get things from another table.

Comment: On the same connection you select @@IDENTITY

Comment: No, please don't use `@@IDENTITY`. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is a much better habit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the title by "columns not inserted into the table"? Can you clarify or re-word the question?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I was about to write the same thing, don't use `@@IDENTITY`. Either `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or `IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)`

Comment: Your text states `I am inserting only 1 column into TempId table i.e name`, yet your query shows that you're inserting two fields: `name` and `orderid`.  Overall this is a bit vague or unclear, and a bit contradictory.  Could you clarify exactly what you need, what you've tried, and why it didn't work?

Comment: Or use an `OUTPUT` clause since `SCOPE_IDENTITY` isn't reliable.  [Ref](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value).

Comment: tempId has only two columns , one is an identitiy column and the other is a varchar field. I need the inserted identity values along with the corresponding orderIds ( which are not inserted into tempID).

Comment: @Lamak never use ident_current(tablename for this) this is not limited to the scope of tehinsert and will, guaranteed, cause dataintegrity problems if two peoplehappen to run a process at the same time!

Answer (score 3):

You put the id and any other fields you need to use later in a table varaiable or temp table by using the OUTPUT clause

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table( ID int, orderid int);
INSERT mytable (field1, orderID)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.OrderID
        INTO @MyTableVar
SELECT FIELD2, orderid FROM Myothertable
```

Now you have the data available in  @MyTableVar to do inserts to child tables or the other work you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

just arrange the columns:

```
create table #tempID( id int, name varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #tempID (name, id)
output inserted.ID 
Select name, orderid FROM (
select 'erty' as name, 1 as orderid union 
select 'rth' as name, 2 as orderid union 
select 'yt' as name, 3 as orderid union 
select '345' as name, 4 as orderid union 
select 'rtyu' as name, 5 as orderid union 
select 'uio' as name, 6 as orderid union 
select 'yu' as name, 7 as orderid union 
select 'xzf' as name, 8 as orderid
) as a
```

Comment: As I read the question the OP wants the identity. This answer does not address identity.  Create table #tempID( id int, name varchar(50)) does not create an identity.  You can't insert a value for identity.  The identity value is created by the table insert.

Answer (score -4):

This is an example on inserting values directly.  If there are no triggers you can get @@IDENTITY.

```
  insert into [FTSwordDef] ([word]) values ('value') 
  select scope_identity();
```

Scope_identity (and the evil @@) will only return the last iden.   If you are inserting multiple rows then I think you would need to loop in a SP and build up the list of iden.   Iden is created by the insert and is not available IN the insert to my knowledge.

If you held a tablock on the the insert and retrieved the last identity and how many rows were inserted then in theory the insert got the last x inden values.  If your insert was sorted you would know what iden went with which row.

Comment: See replies to your comment.  Simply -do-not- use @@identity.  It is not thread safe, scope safe, or any other kind of safe.  There is no reason to use it when you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY().  Also, the OPs example shows multiple rows being inserted.  Using OUTPUT wil give the ids for multiple rows, any of the identity methods will only give a single value back.

Comment: he's inserting multiple rows, SCOPE_IDENTITY() will get only the last ID inserted

Comment: @Diego I agree and that is why I phrased my answer as an "example".

Comment: @Diego Did you vote my answer down?  My answer returns 1 identity - your answer returns 0 identity.

Comment: IT is downvoted because it isnot only incorrect it is dangerous advice.  OUTPUT is the only method to get the id value back when you insert multiple records. Any one who mentions using @@identity should be downvoted because those uof use who know what we are doing know that it doesn't matter if there is trigger now, ther may bea trigger later.

Comment: No I did not and I don't know why you vote mine down because mine returns all the order ids inserted, exactly what the user requested "How do i get corresponding orderId for the identity column."
You misunderstood the question and provided a wrong answer

Comment: If I voted yours down it was my mistake and I removed it.  My answer says scope_identity() and I identify the pitfall of using @IDENTITY.